# How can fetch data on the basis of location in Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch shops on the basis of user location in Firestore.

**Firestore structure:**

```
shopCollection
        shopDoc1
            city:"city",
            address:"xyz",
               lat:35,
               long:25
        shopDoc2....
```

I want to retrieve all the shops that are near to user with distance. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to simply query the Firestore database and get all shops that are nearby. To solve this, you need to use a library and for that I recommend you to use [GeoFirestore for Android](https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-Android):

> GeoFirestore is an open-source library for Android that allows you to store and query a set of documents based on their geographic location.

Comment: I just video on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mx1mMdHBi5Q it would not work in android ?

Comment: As I see, is not for Android. Never tested something like that but as I'm aware of, the above library can help you solve this problem.

Comment: people use this library in production?

Comment: I'm not sure about it. I just played with it but I saw many question here on SOF related to this topic. I also know that it's not a library made by Google/Firebase team but I think you should give it a try.

Comment: Thank you @alexa Mamo I will try it

Comment: I'm not sure about it stilll.when I will use this then definitely i will mark it